# Avoid Transparent pixels of an image

Tags: java, gwt

I use GWT and I want to implement a simple MouseMoveHandler on an image.
So I simply implement it like this :

```
Image icon = new Image(Context.IMAGES.infoIcon());
        icon.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
                int left = event.getScreenX();
                int top = event.getScreenY();

            }
        });
```

This is OK, but I want the event avoid transparent pixels.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think of is to draw the picture on an HTML5 canvas. Then analyze every pixels RGB values and decide whether to handle the event or not.

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
Image imagePng = new Image("test.png");

if (_canvas != null) {
  panel.add(canvas);
} else {
  // No canvas support in this browser
  panel.add(imagePng);
}

canvas.getContext2d().drawImage(ImageElement.as(imagePng.getElement()), 0, 0);
```

Then later in your MouseHandler code. Evaluate the position of the mouse handler on the image (x, y), then analyze the image color on this position.

```
int width = canvas.getOffsetWidth();
int height = canvas.getOffsetHeight();

ImageData imageData = canvas.getContext2d().getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

int r = imageData .getRedAt(x, y);
int g = imageData .getGreenAt(x, y);
int b = imageData .getBlueAt(x, y);

if (!isRGBValueTransparent(r, g, b)) {
  // Do something;
}
```

The code can be improved, if you don't do the calculation every time but keep some kind of matrix where you store whether a pixel is transparent or not. Then just look it up in said matrix.